# Regular expression to match beginning letter of second word

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Consider these names:
sathya , subha , selvi, shalini and ashok selvam

I coded as`(  'firstname': new RegExp('^' + req.body[fieldName], 'i')    )` which means, If i enter 's' in searchtext box, it will display all the name starts with 's'.

But in the name ashok selvam, second word is beginning with 's'. I want this name also to display when i entered 's' in searchtext box.

Which regular expression I have to use to get the result?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Try `new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + req.body[fieldName], 'i')`. If the search string may contain special chars, you may need to escape it, `new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + req.body[fieldName].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'i')`

Comment: It is working fine

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155678/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider [upvoting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an alternaton non-capturing group `(?:^|\\s)` instead of a mere `^`:

```
new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + req.body[fieldName], 'i')
```

Now, the search will be performed at the start of string or after a whitespace.

If the search string may contain special chars, you may need to escape it:

```
new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + req.body[fieldName].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
( 'firstname': new RegExp('(^' + req.body[fieldName] + ')|(.*\s+' + req.body[fieldName] + ')', 'i') )
```

Comment: this one is working like old one. can you please explain this?